# Adjusting a UILabel for different screen sizes with AutoLayout Using MultiLines

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, autolayout

I have a simple `UITableViewController` where the `cells` are custom sizes and there are two `UILabels` in the cell; one for a question and one for an answer.

It was designed for the **iPhone 5** and used the guidelines rather than `AutoLayout`. With the **iPhone 6**, I am of course looking into `AutoLayout` and while I have it implemented on the rest of my app, I am stuck with this part.

The screenshot is below:

[image]

On the **iPhone 5s**, it's set to be right at the edge, but as you can see, on the **6 Plus**, it looks terrible because it's not **"auto-extending"**.

I have tried the following:

- Set the leading, trailing, top and bottom edge of the top label (Q: I get confused). I have set the lines to be 0 in the inspector and set a "width" constraint of greater than 320. That did nothing and I'm still getting the same results.

The reason I set the leading, trailing, top and bottom is that it should always be tied to each edge, etc.. But I just don't know how to get it to Auto extend depending on the screen size.

It's a `UITableView` because of the built in scrolling and I've removed the cell lines for clarity here.

Any guidance on this would really be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure it will fix your problem, but you shouldn't have a width constraint on the label -- the leading and trailing constraints are enough to define the width of the label.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rdelmar - unfortunately, removing that width constraint didn't help as you mentioned.. I can't imagine this is difficult.. It needs to resize the UILabel, but then, it needs to actually show the appropriate words on the appropriate lines.. I'm stuck on it though!

Comment: Are you using size classes in IB? I think you need to give more detail about the constraints you set up, because it seems like what you did should work.

Comment: With a bit of work, I figured this out. With the iPhone 5 implementation, I realised that in the actual UILabel, I was putting in new lines so that it spills over to the next line on screen. With removing this, and removing the width constraint, this works like a charm on different device sizes. Thanks again - do you want to just answer this so I can accept it?